Index match in Power Query M
I have data that looks like the below example. There is a unique list of IDs in the ID column, a data type in the second column a secondary ID in the third column (which maps to an ID in the first column) and a value in the fourth column. I am trying to come up with a M query that allows me to create the Final result column. I the data is of type "type 1", the final result should be the value (fourth column) corresponding to the ID in the third column. If the data is of type "type 2", the final result should just be the value in the third column and if the data is of type "type 3" the final result should be null, empty or whatever.
I am having issues with the logic for the data type 1.
How can I go about constructing this final result column?
Data example:



ID
Type
corr_ID
Value
Final result




c.22
type 1
c.23

aa


c.23
type 2

aa
aa


c.12
type 1
c.20

bb


c.14
type 1
c.23

aa


c.20
type 2

bb
bb


c.21
type 3





c.5
type 3





c.10
type 2
c.20

bb



I have tried  the following:
if [Type] = "type 2" then [Value]
else if [Type] = "type 1" then
try Table.SelectRows(#"PromotedHeaders", each [ID] = [corr_ID]){0}[Value]
else null

However I can not get any matching. I have verified that the IDs in the first and third column don't have trailing/leading spaces, have the same length.
Even this:
if Text.From([ID]) = Text.From([corr_ID]) then "Match" else "No Match"

gives me only "No matches"

You can define a custom function to perform the lookup for type 1 and create a lookup table that pairs ID with Value for the reference :
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WStYzMlLSUSqpLEhVMAQygHxjIKUUqxMNY4PlQIqAKDERKmOIrssAocvQBI+JBmgmJiXBZAxhMsYQGai4KXZhQxSD4A6IBQA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [ID = _t, Type = _t, corr_ID = _t, Value = _t]),
    
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", type text}, {"Type", type text}, {"corr_ID", type text}, {"Value", type text}}),

    LookupValue = (corr_ID as text, LookupTable as table) as nullable text =>
        let
            matchingRow = Table.SelectRows(LookupTable, each [ID] = corr_ID),
            result = if Table.RowCount(matchingRow) > 0 then matchingRow{0}[Value] else null
        in
            result,

    LookupTable = Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type", {"ID", "Value"}),

    AddFinalResult = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Final result", each
        if [Type] = "type 2" then [Value] 
        else if [Type] = "type 1" then 
            LookupValue([corr_ID], LookupTable) 
        else
            null 
    )
in
    AddFinalResult



This should work:
Table.AddColumn(Source, "Final Results", (row)=> if row[Type] = "type 2" then row[Value] else if row[Type] = "type 1" then Table.SelectRows(Source, (r)=>r[ID] = row[corr_ID]){0}[Value] else null)


The problem with your code is that in Table.SelectRows(#"PromotedHeaders", each [ID] = [corr_ID]), both [ID] and [corr_ID] mean ID and corr_ID for the current row.
e.g for row1, what you want to do is to filter out rows where ID = c.23.
So you need to specify c.23 as row[corr_ID], where row means the row you are adding this "Final Results" column to. (that is, row1);
And you need to specify ID as r[ID], where r serves as an iterator for the original source table.
To write it in an easy to understand double for loop, it is kind of like this:
for each row in Source:
   corr_ID = row[corr_ID]
   selected = []
   for each r in Source:
      if r[ID] = corr_ID:
         selected.Add(r)


Similar to rachel's, with error handling:
let
  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "Table1"]}[Content],
  finalResult = Table.AddColumn(
    Source,
    "Final result",
    each
      if [Type] = "type 2" then
        [Value]
      else if [Type] = "type 1" then
        try
          Table.SelectRows(Source, (r) => r[ID] = [corr_ID]){0}[Value]
        otherwise
          Text.Format("** error: #{0} not found **", {[corr_ID]})
      else
        ""
  )
in
  finalResult


